# Ubuntu 13.04 Slow boot on Insipiron 15R SE

Tags: 13.04, bootchart

I have a "trial-boot" win7,win8 and ubuntu 13.04, getting some extreme slowly boot on Ubuntu...

Win8 and win7 works fine...

Here is my [BootChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6oi5.png).

Some one knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This was HUGE for me

http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2009/06/04/mount-options-to-improve-ext4-file-system-performance/

Also

make sure "preload" is installed

sudo apt-get install preload

then when you boot, hit e when grub comes up, arrow over and add the word "profile" without the quotes, then hit crtl+x to boot.

Comment: By looking at his bootchart, mounting is not the issue here.

Comment: I have installed preload and edited grub boot script adding profile on the end of the line and got the same thing. i cant find what is slowing the boot, on my bootchart

Comment: i founf the problem... speech-dispatcher... i only deactivate with bum and now the boot are taking less time, thanks for the help!

Comment: @JhonathanGarciadeSouza Provide that as an asnwer to your question rather than a comment. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the OP (given in a comment)

---

I found the problem... speech-dispatcher... I deactivated it with *bum* and now the boot is taking less time.